# Why is the text not working?

Tags: css, html, linear-gradients

I was experimenting with some HTML/CSS. I was positioning a h5 but it isn't working. When I position it, the top bar would scoot down. It should be flush with the top of its container. Here's my code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title>Hello world!</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css"/>
            <script src="js/site.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <!-- window wrapper -->
            <div id="wrapper">
                <!-- top bar -->
                <div id="top_bar">
                    <!-- title -->
                    <h6 class="title">Hello</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Now for the CSS.

```
    body {
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
        background: url("http://media.idownloadblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Yosemite-Preview.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center center;
    }

    #wrapper {
        height: 500px;
        width: 1000px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px gray;
    }

    #top_bar {
        background: linear-gradient(rgba(220,220,220,0.8),rgba(225,225,225,0.8),rgba(215,215,215,0.8));
        margin-top: 0px;
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        border-top-left-radius: 5px;
        border-top-right-radius: 5px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }

    .title {
        text-align: center;
    }
```

So PLEASE help guys, I don't know what's wrong.

P.S. Don't mind the background image.

Comment: Where is H5 in your code? and H6 seems to be showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
.title {
        text-align: center;
    margin-top:0px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Mark's answer will work.

Your browser is adding its own styles. In this case, it is adding a top and bottom margin.

In chrome:

[image: h6]

You can set `margin-top: 0` to your title to override this or remove the margins completely with `margin: 0` and add `padding: 2.33em 0;` to emulate the same spacing.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/JD7pe/)